# how to get cursor to show all arguments that start with the same string sequence in android

Tags: java, android, cursor

I have a table with names, and I want the user to get a list of all the name that star with the same letters even if he doesn't know the full name. I used the regular code, but that gives me only a direct mach, what is missing? :

```
private Cursor getCursor(String pTableName, String pEntry) {
    return db.query(pTableName,
                    new String[]{"_id", "PRIVET", "FAMILY"},
                    "PRIVET= ?",
                    new String[]{pEntry},
                    null, null, "PRIVET ASC");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `like` operator:

```
return db.query(pTableName,
                new String[]{"_id", "PRIVET", "FAMILY"},
                "PRIVET LIKE ? || '%'",
                new String[]{pEntry},
                null, null, "PRIVET ASC");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but, this only works partially, when I enter the first two letter it give me a list' but when I enter the third letter. the app crashes. Something is still missing.

Comment: @אריאלעדן you'll have to provide a lot details than "the app crashes"

Comment: I found the problem it was my mistake, the code works fine. Thanks.